# Correct way to restar/reload application for a different release

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, pm2, process-management

I have following folder structure:

```
current
releases
  2192091029019/
  1029012901920/
```

Latest release gets pushed to current folder, and I afterwards start it wiht `pm2 start`, however If I upload new release with different folder name and do `pm2 reload` from new folder it still trys to reference original release from where application was started. Is there a way to restart application respecting new code?

Comment: Did you read http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/capistrano-like-deployments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem with this release structure but with `supervisord`+`Rails` instead `pm2` + `node`.
In my case i need to completely restart `supervisord` every deploy to fix that.
So in your case it may work like this:

```
pm2 stop
kill -SIGTERM {pm2_pid}
pm2 startup
```

It's hackish but working solution.

Comment: See this way you kind loose this "no downtime" feature that pm2 is so useful for

Comment: This problem left me two options - the rejection of the supervisord or the rejection of a release structure. I have rejected supervisord after i wasted a lot of time to get it work. As a result we implemented monitoring features with `monit`. I hope it exists better solution for pm2.